# Probability on card without replacement

Tags: probability

Can you help me solving this with a combinatorial approach?

Suppose we randomly select $5$ cards without replacement from an ordinary deck of playing cards. What is the probability of getting exactly $2$ red cards?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  You should show what you have attempted and  explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Yeah sure...will keep this in my mind... this was my first question asked in stack exchange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to math stack exchange! Usually you are asked to show what you've been thinking. However, I will try to give you a hint so you can start.

First of all, in an ordinary deck of playing cards there are 52 cards, 26 of them black, 26 of them red.

So for example, the probability of extracting one red card is obviously $1/2$. You could start by asking yourself, what is the probability that you extract two red cards first, followed by three black cards (which is one among other posibilities of doing what you are asking for).

So the probability of extracting two red first, followed by three black would be:

$$\frac{26}{52}\cdot \frac{25}{51} \cdot \frac{26}{50} \cdot \frac{25}{49} \cdot \frac{24}{48}$$

Now, another posibility is taking the first red, the second black, the third red and the last two black for example. How many $\textit{different}$ posibilities are there?

Hint: The total probability would be the sum of the probabilities of each of these posibilities!

Comment: Yeah but I needed the combinatorial approach for this solution...

Comment: Well you should have included it in the question (before your edit)

Comment: @ShashankDixit the word "combinatorial" has multiple definitions. This solution is actually a combinatorial approach. From the Merriam-Webster Dictionary: "Combinatorial: of or relating to the arrangement of, operation on, and selection of discrete mathematical elements belonging to finite sets or making up geometric configurations". So, it may behoove you to explain what you mean by combinatorial approach.

Comment: Thanku @InterstellarProbe

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at the problem is using combinations. From the 26 red cards, choose 2. From the 26 black cards, choose 3. Divide by the total number of ways to choose 5 cards from the deck of 52.

$$\dfrac{({_{26}C_2})({_{26}C_3})}{({_{52}C_5})}$$